# FPGrowth on a Dataframe?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, data-mining, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Let's say I have a Dataframe of this structure:

```
time| asset | parameter  
----|-------|----------
T1  |  A1   | P1
T1  |  A1   | P2
T1  |  A1   | P3
T1  |  A2   | P1
T1  |  A2   | P2
T1  |  A2   | P3
T2  |  A1   | P1
....
```

And so on

I want to use the `FPGrowth` API (as part of `spark.mllib`) on this dataframe, where all parameters corresponding to the same timestamp is considered as a transaction. How do I go about this?

The example given in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) talks simply of a file being read, each line corresponding to a different transaction.

I am new to Spark, so help of any kind is welcome!
(Spark version 1.6.2 with Scala)

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data, so that you have one row per transaction.

Then run FPgrowth.

Comment: That's alright if your dataframe isn't so big. My dataframe can have millions of data points or more. In such a situation pivoting it would be time consuming wouldn't it?

Comment: If the data is sorted, this is O(n) - not too bad. FP-Growth needs the data in transactions, so you will have to pay this runtime cost eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Append column name to each of the row values. Your Dataframe will look like this:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| time     | asset       | parameter   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| time:T1  |  asset:A1   | parameter:P1|  
| time:T1  |  asset:A1   | parameter:P2|  
| time:T1  |  asset:A1   | parameter:P3|
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

This makes values unique